# Truffle Contract and nodejs

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle

I want to send a data to a function created in a smart contract.

```
function notarizeHash(uint256 id, bytes32 documentHash) public onlyOwner noHashExistsYet(id) {
        hashesById[id] = documentHash;

        emit ProofCreated(id, documentHash);
    }
```

How can I call this function in backend using truffle contract? Or need I do it with send transaction and if yes how?

Comment: You can do it directly with web3. You need to sign a transaction and send it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need Truffle, you can do it directly with Web3, for example (tested with web3.js v1.2.1):

```
async function send() {
    const web3        = new Web3(YOUR_NODE_ADDRESS);
    const contract    = new web3.eth.Contract(YOUR_CONTRACT_ABI, YOUR_CONTRACT_ADDRESS);
    const account     = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY);
    const transaction = contract.methods.notarizeHash(YOUR_ID, YOUR_DOCUMENT_HASH);

    const options  = {
        to      : transaction._parent._address,
        data    : transaction.encodeABI(),
        gas     : await transaction.estimateGas({from: account.address}),
        gasPrice: WHATEVER_GAS_PRICE_YOU_ARE_WILLING_TO_PAY
    };

    const signed  = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(options, account.privateKey);
    const receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signed.rawTransaction);

    return receipt;
}
```

Comment: @Subik: Have you tried it?